# Facebook connect login in Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website that uses the Facebook login button and

connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

As of friday, I started getting a cross-origin security error when new users were trying to log in.

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Instead of redirecting after login, the dialog box just turns to a blank white screen.

This is only happening in Chrome. Everything runs smoothly in Safari and Firefox.

Anyone else experiencing these issues?

Any ideas about a possible fix?

Comment: We can't be reasonably expected to help you without seeing any of your code.

Comment: either check out the source code at www.faceworld3d.com or here: http://jsfiddle.net/4uRbb/